# Text overflow only not works in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

The truncated text in a paragraph just not working in Firefox.
Any idea?

## Chrome

[image]

## Firefox

[image]

```
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical !important;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
    line-height: 1.3em !important;
    height: 5.6em !important;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
-moz-binding: url('ellipsis.xml#ellipsis');
display: block;
```

The Qwertiy suggestion is a good way to resolve that. 
I made an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/3xb23suk/1/

Comment: Could you provide a working example of multiline text with ellipsis? Seems like the code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Sorry, that just worked for a single line. Your idea it's good: "...to show a gradient instead of ellipsis."

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is based on obsolete `-webkit-box` display. Only webkit-based browsers support it. If you want to support Opera 12, you can use `text-overflow: -o-ellipsis-lastline` on normal block. All other browsers have no any functionality allowing to make multiline ellipsis.

You have to write a script for measuring the text and cropping it somehow.

The other possible way is to show a gradient instead of ellipsis.